# I want to modify the properties of a button during the execution (example button-text, click behavior).

Tags: android, xml, button

In this layout for example, after 10 qr scans i want the button to say "send email" instead of "Scan qr" and want it to open different activity (or any other behavior)when clicked. please explain how can i do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_scan"
        android:background="@color/mybackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.sdemo.ScanActivity">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scanning QR"
            style="@style/myHeading"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/mySubHeading"
                android:id="@+id/scan_tips"
                android:text="@string/scan_tips"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:text="Scan QR"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/myButton"
            android:id="@+id/button_start_scan"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

java file

```
    package com.example.android.sdemo;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            import com.google.zxing.Result;
            import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

    public class ScanActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
        private  ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v){
            setContentView(mScannerView);
            mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            mScannerView.startCamera();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mScannerView.stopCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result){
    //        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intentBack = new Intent(getApplication(), StoryActivity.class);
            intentBack.putExtra("qrResult", result.getText());
            startActivity(intentBack);
            //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

Declare button, a counter globally:

```
   int count = 0;
   Button btn;
```

In `onCreate` initilize button:

```
  btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start_scan);
```

Modify `onClick()` method as below:

```
 public void onClick(View v){
     if(count<10){
          setContentView(mScannerView);
          mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
          mScannerView.startCamera();
      }
      else{
           btn.setText("Send Email");
           // send mail here
       }
       count++;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your onclicklistener do this

```
Button bt=(Button)view;
bt.seText("Clicked!");
```